# What is the Hilbert space in quantum field theory?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, hilbert-space

My understanding is that in classical field theory, we study a classical field $\phi(x,t)$ where for each $x\in\mathbb{R}^3$, $t\in\mathbb{R}$, $\phi(x,t)$ is a scalar. In quantum field theory, we promote each $\phi(x,t)$ to an operator $\hat{\phi}(x,t)$ on an Hilbert space.

My questions are:

1. Given a problem, how do we know what that Hilbert space is? Is it some sort of Fock space?
2. Does every $\hat{\phi}(x,t)$ act on the same Hilbert space?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quantum fields (as defined by the [Wightman axioms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wightman_axioms)) are operator-valued distributions. We must smear them with a test function $f$ (usually a [Schwartz space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartz_space) function) to obtain an (in general unbounded) operator on a Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$:
$$\phi(f) := \int_{\mathbb{R}^{d+1}} f(x,t) \phi(x,t) \ \mathrm{d} x \mathrm{d} t.$$
The Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$ is part of the data that defines a QFT model. This Hilbert space does not need to be a Fock space.

To answer your second question, the Wightman axiom W1 in the linked Wikipedia entry demands that a dense subspace $D \subset \mathcal{H}$ exists such that, for each test function $f$, the smeared quantum field $\phi(f)$ is an operator with domain $D$. Thus, the smeared quantum fields act on the same Hilbert space with common dense domain $D$.

Comment: What do you mean by: "$\mathcal{H}$ is usually a Fock space"? As far as I recall, a Fock space is the infinite direct sum of direct sums of Hilbert spaces.

Comment: A Fock space $\mathcal{F}$ is an infinite direct sum of tensor products of a (one-particle) Hilbert space $\mathfrak{h}$, i.e. $\mathcal{F} = \bigoplus_{n\in\mathbb{N}} \mathfrak{h}^{\otimes n}$, and therefore $\mathcal{F}$ is also a Hilbert space.

Comment: @Janik Could you expand on why one cannot assume that an interacting theory has an associated Fock space?

Comment: @MartinC. I think it's a reference to Haag's theorem. But in the Schrodinger formulation of QFT, a *wavefunctional* evolves in time according to Schrodinger equation. I don't see how the states of interacting theories aren't wavefunctionals. Is the Schrodinger formulation of QFT wrong somehow?

Comment: In principle, you could assume that the Hilbert space is a Fock space as all Hilbert spaces are isomorphic. However, these isomorphisms are not compatible with a Wightman QFT. For example, consider representations of the canonical commutation relations (CCRs). According to Haag's theorem infinitely many unitarily inequivalent representations of CCRs exist. One of these representations is a Fock representation, but there are infinitely many more representations which may not be a Fock representation. See also https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/264279